# "error -5014" when mounting a SMB network volume

Tags: mount, smb, file-sharing

When I mount a remote SMB volume with macOS's file sharing feature like as:

`osascript -e 'mount volume "smb://USER@MACOS_SERVER/VOLNAME"`

but it fails with `Error -5014`.

What I tried were:

- rebooting the client
- restarting `smbd` with kill/launchctl on the server
- on/off "File Sharing" at "Sharing" of Preferences app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to D.R.C.'s answer in [What is Error -5014 ?? - Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1155515?answerId=5459319022#5459319022), one possible solution is to remove 'Apple' files on the volume, such as:

- `.AppleDB, .AppleDesktop, :2eDS_Store, .DS_Store, etc.` mentioned by D.R.C.
- and also `.DAV, .TemporaryItems, .apdisk, ._*`.

I tried removing these files and the error went away.

Comment: I get this error trying to mount a volume that doesn't have any of these files. (Yes, I know how to turn invisible files on so I could see them if they were there.)

Answer (score 0):

This is often a network-related issue.

For my latest encounter with this error, it was caused by having the [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com) Mac client installed and connected with the **Use Tailscale DNS Settings** option enabled, which resulted in DNS queries for the name of the SMB server to resolve incorrectly to the server TailScale IP address rather than the internal LAN IP address of the server (which was also not connected to Tailscale at the time).

Disabling the **Use Tailscale DNS Settings** option restored connectivity without error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for anyone else, I was able to get this to work on Mojave with these Terminal commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/smb
mount -t smbfs //username@other-computer-name.local/MacintoshHD ./smb/
```

This mounted "other-computer-name.local" in the Finder, and I was able to open it and mount MacintoshHD without any error. Absolutely nothing else worked: I kept getting either error -5014 from the command line, "the original item could not be found" errors trying to mount it through the shared volume under Network in Finder, or "Server could not be found" when using "Connect to Server..." in Finder.